# In ReactJS, how do you change the border color of all items when you select something in a form component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm new in Reactjs and would love any help on how to apply it.

I have a form component that when you select (+), its border color and the rest of the items within it will turn to green such as the description, value and the check button. When I select the (-), its border color and the rest of the items will turn red as well.

How do you change the border color of all items when you select the (+) or (-) in a form component?

[+ is selected, all items border color is changed as well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTaQo.png)

Comment: what you have tried or think

Comment: What i'm thinking is on the select there's an onChange that will get the type which is inc(+) or exp(-) then based on that type the mystyle={borderColor: "red"} or mystyle={borderColor: "green"} will be pass to those items. Ex description style={mystyle}. Just don't know yet how to do it. Each item has style={mystyle}. Any suggestions and help is greatly appreciated. Thanks Lenoarod

Comment: you can try this answer(https://stackoverflow.com/a/46900432/5705408)

Answer (score 0):

This would be easy with the below steps.

Store your colors into global variables.
`const formColor1 = '#aaaaaa';`
`const formColor2 = '#bbbbbb'`

Set the border color as a state inside the constructor method.
`this.state = {formColor: '#cccccc'}`

Use this state in style inside any JSX component.
`style={{backgroundColor: this.state.formColor}}`

Update the state accordingly when the button is pressed.
`this.setState({formColor: formColor1})`